# ¿Cómo mandar a llamar un StoredProcedure de SQL con Php?

Tags: php

Hola requiero de su ayuda Tengo un storedprocedure el cual lo mando a llamar en php para que me muestre el resultado pero me esta marcando error.

Este es el codigo que tengo

```
<?php  
include_once "../Controlador/conexion.php";
$dia = '20221210';
$inspector = 'Daniela Chaparro';

$stmt = sqlsrv_query($cnx,"Call PIVOT_INSP()");

sqlsrv_prepare($stmt, '@dat', $dia, PDO::PARAM_STR, false, false);
sqlsrv_prepare($stmt, '@inspector', $inspector, PDO::PARAM_STR, false, false,250);

$result = sqlsrv_execute($stmt);

while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $row[0],  ', ', $row[1], "\r\n";
}


?>
```

Pero marca este error

[image: error que se muestra al correr el codigo]
Y esto es lo que me muestra si hago una consulta al storedprocedure desde sql y es lo que quiero que se vea con php
[image: Consulta del Stored Procedure en la BD]

Este es el StoredProcedure que e creado en SQL
[image: StoredProcedure]

Comment: ¿Por qué [preparas](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.sqlsrv-prepare.php) dos veces la misma sentencia?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¿Ya probaste colocar en tu sentencia SQL los parámetros incluidos?

```
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($cnx,"EXECUTE PIVOT_INSP @dat='". $dia. "'", @inspector='" . $inspector . "'");
```

Ya no sería necesario declarar los parámetros con el $stmt_prepare

Comment: si me sirvió muchas gracias